# how to run Multi-Mechanize Performance Test python script for multiple page urls

Tags: python, multithreading, mechanize

Hi I using mechanize test framework here i am running this script to test a page its working fine if i have only one page

```
import mechanize

class Transaction(object):
    def run(self):
        br = mechanize.Browser()
        br.set_handle_robots(False)
        resp = br.open('http://www.example.com/')
        resp.read()
```

now i have 15 urls and i want to read them  from a file and want to put them in this place

```
resp = br.open('http://www.example.com/')
```

but i am not able to do this because as run method runs multiple times and give response that i am not able to handel

May be i am not too much clear please have look on this discription

http://testutils.org/multi-mechanize/scripts.html

I am very new to python so i am not able to handel this tried google searching but haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an (global) array of the websites in init() which is only called once and then you can  write a for loop to open each of the websites in the array.